# Laravel 5 PHPUnit - Invalid JSON was returned from the route

Tags: php, json, laravel, routes, phpunit

**Routes**

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'api'), function() {
   Route::resource('test', 'TestController', array('only' => array('index', 'store', 'destroy', 'show', 'update')));
});
```

**Controller**

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    return response()->json(['status' => true]);
}
```

**Unit Class**

```
public function testBasicExample() {
    $this->post('api/test')->seeJson(['status' => true]);
}
```

PHPUnit result:

1) `ExampleTest::testBasicExample`

> Invalid JSON was returned from the route.

Perhaps an exception was thrown?  Anyone see the Problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is the **CSRF Token**.

You could [disable the middleware](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/testing#disabling-middleware) by using the `WithoutMiddleware` trait:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;

class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    use WithoutMiddleware;

    //
}
```

Or, if you would like to only disable middleware for a few test methods, you may call the `withoutMiddleware` method from within the test methods:

```
<?php

class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic functional test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testBasicExample()
    {
        $this->withoutMiddleware();

        $this->visit('/')
             ->see('Laravel 5');
    }
}
```

Comment: is there a way to see the exception that was thrown?

Comment: To view the exception: 
        $this->json('POST', 'api/test');
        dd($this->response->getContent());

Comment: In Lumen WithoutMiddleware  is not there. Any one know how to install this?

Comment: For lumen, `use Laravel\Lumen\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;`

@KirenSiva